# Programmatically accessing the Windows file allocation table

Tags: windows, fat

How can I programmatically access the file allocation entries (FAT) in Windows? I have read the articles which mention reading entries at a particular address in the harddisk, but how can I read those entries from the harddisk. I can try in C, C++, C# or VB.

The tutorials on http://www.ntfs.com were helpful in understanding what to read on the FAT, but didn't clarify how to do so programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the hard drive itself with the file I/O functions like [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) and [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx).  You can open the disk using CreateFile, seek to the appropriate sector using [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541(VS.85).aspx), and then read using ReadFile.

See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027) for more details about reading data directly from the disk.

Comment: so how can i make use of the readfile function to read the FAT entry data?